# Показывать меню окна в Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Установил Ubuntu 18.04,пропали меню окна.
Как вернуть ? Заранее спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То, что вы показываете на скриншоте мышкой - и есть меню окна, а следовательно оно не пропало? Просто переместилось непосредственно из самого окна в верхнюю панель.

В настройках рабочего стола (там же где меняются заставки), нужно поставить галочку, точно не помню, что-то типа "отображать меню внутри окна"

Comment: фотография из интернета как пример.

Comment: ctrl+shift+m попробуйте

Comment: ctrl+shift+m не помогло